# Twilio: Purging media resources older than a certain time automatically

Tags: resources, twilio, media, mms, purge

Everytime we send an image MMS with Twilio, they keep a copy of the image on their server.

Does Twilio have a API function or an account setting to delete image resources older than a certain time (rather than deleting them one by one with the Delete Media Resource API)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no account setting to delete images automatically, based on time or anything else. As [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/media) says (emphasis mine):

> Twilio will keep that media around **until you issue an HTTP DELETE on that instance**.

Every time you send a message you could schedule a job to run in the future to then delete that message's media. That way you are in control of deletion when you want it to happen.